Figma Component Design to Code conversion
I'm exploring ways to convert Figma component designs directly into code. Has the syncfusion, kendo or devexpress component been convertable and what tools or methods would you recommend? I'm particularly interested in solutions that support React or other modern frameworks.
I used builder.io plugin to convert the codes, but it generates the basic code format. Also i'm utilized the AI option provided by builder.io, it also not organized and properly generated.
Check the below image:


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a tool, are explicitly off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
